# Issue on Adding Taxonomy to Custom Post Type Using Function

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy

Using WordPress 3.7.1 and PHP 5.4.12, I am trying to add Custom Post Type and Taxonomy to my Theme, so far the custom post type method works but the Taxonomy is not adding to the Admin Dashboard.

Here is the code I have:

```
<?php
 function add_post_type($name, $args = array()) {
    add_action('init', function() use($name, $args) {
            $upper = ucwords($name);
            $name = strtolower(str_replace(' ','_',$name));
            $args = array_merge(
            array(
            'public'=> true,
            'label' => "All $upper" . 's',
            'labels' => array('add_new_item' => "Add New $upper"),
            'support' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments')
            ),
            $args
            );
            register_post_type('$name', $args);
        });
}

function add_taxonomy($name, $post_type, $args = array()) {
    $name = strtolower($name);
    add_action('init', function() use($name, $post_type, $args) {
            $args = array_merge(
                array(
                'label' => ucwords($name),
                ),
                $args
            );
                register_taxonomy($name, $post_type, $args);
    }); 
}

add_post_type('book', array(
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments')
));
add_taxonomy('fun', 'book');
?>
```

Can you please let me know what part I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need the taxonomy parameter defined in the register function.

Comment: I really need to stop using my iPad for this. What I was meaning is that you need to register the taxonomy ARGUMENT (not parameter) in the `register_post_type` function. See the codex for further instruction: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Taxonomies

Comment: Hey pal, can you give my answer an accept please? Not trying to be rude, but it is the correct answer and I would very much appreciate the reputation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate on my comment ([CPT and Taxonomies connection](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Taxonomies)), you need to allow the registered taxonomy access via the argument on the `register_post_type` function like so:

```
<?php
 function add_post_type($name, $args = array()) {
    add_action('init', function() use($name, $args) {
            $upper = ucwords($name);
            $name = strtolower(str_replace(' ','_',$name));
            $args = array_merge(
            array(
            'public'=> true,
            'label' => "All $upper" . 's',
            'labels' => array('add_new_item' => "Add New $upper"),
            'support' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments'),
            //Add the taxonomy "fun" to this post type
            'taxonomies' => array('fun'),
            ),
            $args
            );
            //Remove quotes from the $name variable
            register_post_type($name, $args);
        });
}


function add_taxonomy($name, $post_type, $args = array()) {
    $name = strtolower($name);
    add_action('init', function() use($name, $post_type, $args) {
            $args = array_merge(
                array(
                'label' => ucwords($name),
                ),
                $args
            );
                register_taxonomy($name, $post_type, $args);
    }); 
}

add_post_type('book', array(
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments')
));
add_taxonomy('fun', 'book');
```

Comment: Hi Nathan, I really appreciate your help but the "fun" taxonomy still not appearing on the page!

Comment: I already tried this with 'taxonomies' => array('post_tag') and it works, I mean added the Post Tag under the Book CPT in dashboard but when ever I add the book custom post type densest!

Comment: Maybe the array_merge in the $args are causing issues with the tax delivery.

Comment: well everything works fine when the 'taxonomies' =>  has been set to tag or post-tag but it is not working when it set to custom taxonomy! does it recreated to the array
_merge?

Comment: I just found the error. `register_post_type('$name', $args);` should be: `register_post_type($name, $args);`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to build new custom Taxonomy to my custom post types. And it works for me.

```
function fun_book() {
// Add new "Fun" taxonomy to Book Post Type
register_taxonomy('fun', 'book', array(
    // Hierarchical taxonomy (like categories)
    'hierarchical' => true,
    // This array of options controls the labels displayed in the WordPress Admin UI
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => _x( 'Fun', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Fun', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Locations' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Fun' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Fun' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Fun:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Fun' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Fun' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Fun' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Fun Name' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Fun' ),
    ),
    // Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'Fun', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
        'with_front' => false, // Don't display the category base before "/locations/"
        'hierarchical' => true // This will allow URL's like "/locations/boston/cambridge/"
    ),
));
}
add_action( 'init', 'fun_book', 0 );
```

I really hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Rayan, Thanks for your comment but I need to run my code for the reuseiblity matter

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry I couldn't be of assistance. If I find another solution I will write back.